# Passing data for radar chart from WIX Velo (javascript) to Chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, radar-chart

I want to plot certain user data (assessment scores on 6 questions at two different time points, namely, initial and current) for the logged-in user as a radar chart.  Here is my setup:

1. Pull user data from the backend database table into a new variable SAI

```
var SAI={  
        Initial:\[val1,val2,val3...,val6\],  
        Current:\[val1,val2,val3...,val6\]  
   }  
   var timing = 'Initial'
```

2. Pass this data to the HTML frame with postMessage

```
$w("#html1").postMessage(SAI\[timing\])
```

3. Use standard radar chart code from Chartjs to render this data

   - Setup the chart with empty data and two series
   - Write the window.onmessage event as follows:

     ```
       window.onmessage = function(event){
         if (event.data && Array.isArray(event.data)) {
           myChart.data.datasets[0].data = event.data;
           myChart.update();
         }
         else {
           console.log("HTML Code Element received a generic message:");
           console.log(event.data);
         }
       };
     ```

This faithfully transmits the SAI[Initial] to the HTML frame, and plots one series, namely, "Initial".  And herein lies my dumb question (after couple of days of futile pursuits trying out different ideas). **"How do I pass two or more data series to HTML frame and make the ChartJS radar chart plot *all* of them?"
**
Full disclaimer: I am new to coding and have limited expertise.  Hence, it will help me immensly if you provide specific code answers based on the above data/code. I am sure I am not the first one to face this issue, but have failed to find any online usable solution and hence, my post in this great forum! :)

Here are my two days of wandering solutions that haven't worked...

1. `$w("#html1").postMessage(JSON.stringify(SAI))` and then, on the HTML frame side used JSON.parse, but the radar chart didn't like the outcome
2. `myChart.data.datasets.forEach(iterate)`.  In this case, didn't stringify the data nor parsed it, but instead tried a function called iterate as follows with no luck:

```
  function iterate() {
    item.data.push(data[cntr]);
    cntr= cntr+ 1
  }
```

3. Tried assigning event.data.datasets[0], threw up error (though dataset length shows up as 2)
4. Tried assigning event.data.datasets.data[0] and then data[1], still got error
5. And also various combinations of the above 4, without any luck

Comment: Your solution #1 should work - there are probably some details that you set wrong. As far as I can see on the docs [postMessage](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/htmlcomponent/postmessage) allows your messages to be objects, so it's possible you could send the whole SAI object without encoding/decoding, the same way you send the array.

Comment: On the other other hand, no serious coder would answer with code written on an imaginary environment, starting from your fragments. Code needs to be tested, otherwise is just guesswork. So, you have two options: 1) the best - provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - this might be rather difficult with the wix environment and your lack of experience 2) provide a lot more code for your attempts, e.g., solution #1, what's your `window.onmessage` - so we can identify the mistakes  you are making.